# Computing Smith normal form of matrix of integers

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations, smith-normal-form

I known that the Smith normal form of $A$ provides two unimodular matrices $U$ and $V$ of respective dimensions $m \times m$ and $n \times n$ such that the matrix
$$B=[b_{i,j}]=UAV$$
and B has the form
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b_{22} & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & 0 & \ldots & b_{ii} & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

But I don't know **how to find the matrices $U$ and $V$**.
For example with the matrix
$$A:= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
2 & 5 \\
-2 & -3 
\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I find the matrices $U$ and $V$ to conclude the Smith normal form?

Comment: I need to know how to find the matrices U and V so that I can solve a problem involving a system of linear Diophantine equations.

Comment: Did you check the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm) section of Wikipedia?

Comment: Hint : Run the row/column process on $\begin{pmatrix} A & I\\I & O\end{pmatrix}$ using the operations you'd use on $A$.